# Get JSON data from php to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

My I have selected some data from database using json.
Now I want to alert the data in javascript.
How do I iterate using for loop from the json data to get the data below in the script.

```
$json_array = array();

$sql = "SELECT id, instructions, quiz_question, correct, wrong, wrong1, wrong2 FROM student_quiz WHERE subject = 'SOCIAL STUDIES' AND type = 'challenge'";

$results = $pdo->query($sql);
$results->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

while($row = $results->fetch()) {
    $json_array['quizlist'][] = $row ;
}

?>

    <script type='text/javascript'>



(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];
```

I need help.

Comment: No need to use `JSON.parse()` if you remove quotes wrapping the php output. Javascript will see it as array already. Any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: [Show/hide message details.] SyntaxError: JSON.parse: expected ',' or '}' that is the console error

Comment: So try `var obj = <?php echo json_encode($json_array);?>;`

Comment: Is working now thanks. But can I get a for loop for this type of data?

Comment: Certainly. You are already accessing an element of the array using index. Can iterate it in any sort of loop you want to use

Comment: <script type='text/javascript'>
  
  
   
(function() {
  var questions = [{
    question: "What is 3*6?",
    choices: [3, 6, 9, 12, 18],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*9?",
    choices: [72, 99, 108, 134, 156],
    correctAnswer: 0
  }, {
    question: "What is 1*7?",
    choices: [4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    correctAnswer: 3
  }, {
    question: "What is 8*8?",
    choices: [20, 30, 40, 50, 64],
    correctAnswer: 4
  }];
  I have a function like this, how can I iterate in it using the data from the json

Comment: `questions.forEach(function(q, i){ console.log(q.question)})`